# Сортировка списка массивов

Tags: java

Имеется список содержащий массивы

```
    TreeList<String[]> familyRegion=new TreeList();
            familyRegion.add(new String[]{"Доктор","Иванов Иван Иванович","12.01.1960","г.Москва"});
            familyRegion.add(new String[]{"Тракторист","Сидоров Иван Петрович","12.01.1970","г.Челябинск"});
            familyRegion.add(new String[]{"Академик","Артюков Альберт Иванович","14.08.1950","г.Москва"});
            familyRegion.add(new String[]{"Стоматолог","Бирюков Петр Иванович","17.01.1960","г.Санкт-Петербург"});
familyRegion.sort(new CompArray());
```

Необходимо отсортировать список по второму элементу (ФИО) я сделал компаратор

```
private class CompArray implements Comparator
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            String[]obj1= (String[]) o1;
            String[]obj2= (String[]) o2;
            return obj1[1].compareTo(obj2[2]);
        }
    }
```

Однако он не работает, подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Наверное, потому что obj2[2] это третий элемент, а не второй.

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья.

Comment: Можешь написать ответ и принять, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Это вообще неправильный подход.
Во-первых, хранить данные о человеке в массиве сток - совсем не вариант.
Во-вторых, какого результата вы ожидаете от сортировки списка массивов? Отсортировать каждый массив по алфавиту, а потом отсортировать массивы между сосбо, исходя из алфавитов каждой переменной??? Я даже это сформулировать не могу... И еще, я не знаю, что такое TreeList, может он совсем не гарантирует порядок элементов(как, например, хешсет), поэтому беру стандартную коллекцию для примера.
Предлагаю пойти нормальным путем:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class Book {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> familyRegion = new ArrayList();
        familyRegion.add(new Person ("Доктор", "Иванов Иван Иванович", LocalDate.of(1960, 1, 12), "г.Москва"));
        familyRegion.add(new Person ("Доктор", "Иванов Иван Иванович", LocalDate.of(1960, 1, 12), "г.Москва"));
        familyRegion.add(new Person ("Тракторист", "Сидоров Иван Петрович", LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 12), "г.Челябинск"));
        familyRegion.add(new Person ("Академик", "Артюков Альберт Иванович", LocalDate.of(1950, 8, 14), "г.Москва"));
        familyRegion.add(new Person ("Стоматолог", "Бирюков Петр Иванович", LocalDate.of(1960, 1, 17), "г.Санкт-Петербург"));
        Collections.sort(familyRegion);
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate birthDate;
    private final String city;
    private final String profession;

    public Person(String profession, String name, LocalDate birthDate, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.city = city;
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        int compareName = name.compareTo(p.getName());
        if (compareName!=0) return compareName;
        else return birthDate.compareTo(p.getBirthDate());
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос часть другой большой задачи завязанной на JTable там необходимо было решить задачу в том виде как она была поставлена.

Comment: значить ваш JTable  работает неправильно. человек отсортирует данные в таблице сначала по имени, потом по дате, потом по городу, а потом выберет запись. как вы теперь свяжете это с моделью? не прикручивайте костылей на таких простых задачах, костылей на ваш век и так хватит

Comment: После исправления ошибки по предыдущему комментарию стала работать как надо, здесь приведен просто пример.

Comment: Можно помочь вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058576/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 0):

```
private class CompArray implements Comparator
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            String[]obj1= (String[]) o1;
            String[]obj2= (String[]) o2;
            return obj1[1].compareTo(obj2[1]);
        }
    }
```